# Adding files - with composer

Tags: php, composer-php

In a project (on which work 2), we are forced to make a "php composer.phar dump-autoload" and "php composer.phar dump-autoload -o" every time we add a new file (a new class in our web project).
If we do not type these lines of command, the autoloader dial tells us that this class is not found ...

Whereas with personal projects, I have never been compelled to type these command lines for each new class of creation.

In my composer.json I have put this:

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4" : {
    "App\\": "app/",
    "Database\\": "app/",
    "Helpers\\": "app/",
    "": [
      "app/",
      "lib/"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thus I does not understand, why, for every time we add a file in the folder " app ", we have to make "php composer.phar dump-autoload" and "php composer.phar dump-autoload -o" ...

ps : I have Classes without Namespace in directories "app" and "lib".

Will you have an idea of where it could come please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason for having to dump the autoloader after adding a new class is when you are using classmap autoloading, and no PSR-0 or PSR-4.

This should be clearly indicated in the `composer.json` file of that application, which would be something like `"autoload":{"classmap":[...]}`.

If this is NOT present, there would be no requirement to dump the autoloader.

If however `composer dump-autoload` does not really work, and `composer dump-autoload -o` is needed, you have errors in your PSR definition of autoloading.

I'm confused whether your excerpt from your `composer.json` is from your nonworking example or not - all I can say is that it is supposed to work without dumping. It still is not optimal, though.